# How to add list( array of strings) and arrayList using collections?

Tags: java, list, arraylist, collections

I am trying to add an array of strings to an arrayList . Below is the code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Arrays;

class AddAll{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] words = {"apples","beef","corn","ham"};
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(words);

        ArrayList<String> arrayList = new ArrayList<String>();
        arrayList.add("Youtube");
        arrayList.add("Google");
        arrayList.add("Facebook");

        for(String x : arrayList){
        System.out.printf("%s ",x);
        }
        System.out.println();

        Collections.addAll(arrayList,list);

      for(String x : arrayList){
        System.out.printf("%s ",x);
    }
  }
 }
```

However, during compilation it throws below error. I am not able to figure out how to resolve it? Can someone help me with this code?

```
  AddAll.java:21: error: method addAll in class Collections cannot be applied to           given types;
    Collections.addAll(arrayList,list);
               ^
  required: Collection<? super T>,T[]
   found: ArrayList<String>,List<String>
  reason: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
  inferred: List<String>
   upper bound(s): String,Object
   where T is a type-variable:
    T extends Object declared in method <T>addAll(Collection<? super T>,T...)
```

1 error

Comment: Where did you see/find a method like `Collections.addAll(arrayList,list);`?

Comment: Advice: if you get a compilation error that tells you that a method cannot be found or applied ... *read the javadocs* ... to find out if the method actually exists, and to check you are calling it with the correct number and types of arguments.

Comment: Hi Stephen, Thank you for the advice. I am just in a learning process. As per your advice I went through javadocs and I could see that method exists. Now the question is how to use it? :(

Comment: The following solved the issue:                                              arrayList.addAll(list);

Answer (score 1):

There is no method in the [`Collections`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) class which accepts two arguments of type `List` or `Collection`.

There is [`List#add(Collection)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#addAll-java.util.Collection-) which can do what you're asking about

```
arrayList.addAll(list);
```

Comment: Thank you Sotirios. Looks like I was going through some old references.